# How to run a function in python only first time the code is running?

Tags: python, function, module

I have written a function that will install the Module required to run a script. My problem is that the function runs every time the script is running. I need to run the function only the first time the script is running so that after installing the module the function does not run every time the script is running.

My code is

```
import importlib
import subprocess
import pkg_resources
import os, time, json, datetime, sys


def import_and_install(package):
    try:
       importlib.import_module(package)
    except (ModuleNotFoundError, pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound) as e:
       print("{0} module is not installed.\n Don't worry.  will take care\n".format(package))
       package = [package]
       subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install'] + package)


packages = ['pandas', 'numpy', 'threading',  'xlwings']

for package in packages:
      import_and_install(package)



import pandas as pd
import threading
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np
```

Comment: ... what exactly is the problem then? Does the script try to run pip to install the package again?

Comment: yes, every time the code is running it try to install packages.

Comment: From the source code it only tries to install the packages if they're not already installed. You'd better check why the import raises the error in the first place

Comment: @user202729 They don't mention an error, they just don't want it to run every time.

Comment: @Kemp I mean if the pip install runs, then the import must raise the error .

Comment: @user202729 Doh, you're right of course. The error definitely needs tracking down then, or adding to the post.

Answer (score 1):

We can compare the list of packages required with the list of packages installed.
To get the list of packages installed we can use:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.working_set
```

This will return an iterator from where we can get the modules installed names (**key**) and versions (**version**).

```
import pkg_resources    
modules_installed = {pkg.key:pkg.version for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}

# this will return a dict like this one, for example:
# {'setuptools': '65.3.0',
#  'pip': '22.2.2',
#  'xlwings': '0.28.5'
#  ...}
```

Now we can compare them with a function that will help to verify if a package is install and also verify the version in case that the package has '==' in the value:

```
# package: for example 'pandas==1.5.0'
# modules_installed: {pkg.key:pkg.version for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}

def is_pkg_installed(package, modules_installed) -> bool:
    pkg_name = package.split('==')[0] if '==' in package else package
    pkg_ver = package.split('==')[1] if '==' in package else None
    if pkg_name not in modules_installed:
        return False
    elif pkg_ver:
        installed_version = modules_installed[pkg_name]
        if pkg_ver != installed_version:
            return False
    return True
```

Using list comprehensions we can get the list of **packages_to_install**:

```
packages_to_install = [package for package in packages_list
                       if not is_pkg_installed(package, modules_installed)]
# values example: packages_to_install = ['pandas==1.5.0', 'numpy']
```

To install the **packages_to_install**, we can use the next function that installs all the packages that are in the list:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def pip_install(packages: list) -> None:
    if not packages:
        return
    # this will do a call like this one:
    # ../python.exe -m pip install pandas=1.5.0, numpy
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install'] + packages)
```

finally the complete example, where **pandas** has a specific version selected **pandas==1.5.0**:

```
import subprocess
import pkg_resources
import sys


def pip_install(packages: list) -> None:
    if not packages:
        return
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install'] + packages)


def is_pkg_installed(package, modules_installed) -> bool:
    pkg_name = package.split('==')[0] if '==' in package else package
    pkg_ver = package.split('==')[1] if '==' in package else None
    if pkg_name not in modules_installed:
        return False
    elif pkg_ver:
        installed_version = modules_installed[pkg_name]
        if pkg_ver != installed_version:
            return False
    return True


def install_packages(packages_list: list) -> None:
    modules_installed = {pkg.key:pkg.version for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
    packages_to_install = [package for package in packages_list
                           if not is_pkg_installed(package, modules_installed)]
    if packages_to_install:
        print(f"{packages_to_install} modules are not installed.\nDon't worry. will take care\n")
        pip_install(packages_to_install)


packages = ['pandas==1.5.0', 'numpy', 'threading', 'xlwings']
install_packages(packages)


import pandas as pd
import threading
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np
```

***install_packages()*** will get the list of packages that are not installed or have different version, and if the list is not empty, run ***pip_install()***

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by running the script only the first time the script is running?.

does that mean you want to run the script only once per computer/VM?.

by the looks of it, it seems that the script that you want to run is for handling dependencies and packaging management, if that is the case I would recommend you use packages manager instead such as Poetry(https://python-poetry.org/).

if you still consist on doing everything on your own.
the simplest solution I could think of Is creating a file that stores a flag that tells you if the script has already ran or not.
but there might be better solutions